# Is this the fourth way to add comment text in SAS?

Tags: sas

As far as I know, there are three kinds of ways to add comment in SAS:

```
*Any comment text here;
%*Any comment text here;
/*Any comment text here*/
```

This afternoon, I am kind of excited of finding the fourth way to add comment by coincidence. It is:

```
comment Any comment text here;
```

As you can see, the first word `comment` is a keyword here to trigger the following text becoming comment text. I have tried several programs:

```
/*comment of macro in open code*/
%put This is %sysfunc(date(),e8601da.);
comment %put This is %sysfunc(date(),e8601da.);

/*comment of macro*/
comment %cmprs(test);

/*comment after normal statement*/
data _null_; comment Hi there.;
run;
```

They all behaves like a normal comment way. Only one point, there mustn't exist a semicolon in the comment text.

I think there is enough exploration in SAS. I search in the help document and find nothing. My friend tells me this may be a pre-experience features, How do you know about it? Please share your idea.

Comment: You can also misspell your comment as `cement this is my comment;`

Comment: @AllanBowe, haha you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COMMENT` is a statement like any other submitted statement.  In essence it is the same as `*` because the comment statement ends at the first semi-colon (`;`).  The documentation does not specifically state `*` is an alias for `COMMENT`, but lists `* ... ;` and `/* ... */`.

Another way to comment multiple statements that also contain comment blocks is to nest the code inside a macro definition.

Example:

```
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

%macro MY_COMMENT;

* This part contains more statements;
proc print sashelp.cars;
run;
/* And there are comments in both styles of commenting */
%* But inside an uncalled macro everything acts like a giant comment block;

%mend MY_COMMENT;

* return to normal processing;
```

For very large blocks of commented code, during development of code, I will often wrap the commented part with `NOSOURCE` and `SOURCE` to prevent log clogging.

```
...

options NOSOURCE;
/*
Big chunk commented out during development to temporarily prevent
rerunning ETL process steps or regenerating already OK reporting code
*/
options SOURCE;

* work on new additional part of process flow here;
...
```

**Other commenting tricks**

**Way 1** - `/**/` *pairs*

If code is consistently commented with only `*;` style comments, then code blocks can be easily commented and uncommented using an *introductory* `/**/` or `/** /` and a closing `/**/` .

Uncommented - the intro is a plain comment

```
/**/  * some code here; /**/
```

Commented - the extra space in the intro causes the comment to be closed by the final `*/`

```
/** / * some code here; /**/
```

**Way 2** - `/* *; */;` toggle

Requires a `*;` comment as the first line of the block, and no `/* */` comments within.

Toggle off, block code is commented out

```
/*
*intro;
... block ...
*/;
```

versus

Toggle on, block code is not commented out

```
*/*
*intro;
... block ...
*/;
```

**Enhanced editor**

- Comment

  - Select a block of lines and press `Ctrl-/`.
    All the lines will become individual `/*original line*/` style comment blocks.
- Uncomment

  - Select a block of lines and press `Ctrl-Shift-/`.
    The leading `/*` and trailing `*/` of each line will be removed.

**Macro variable**

Use a flag variable with value   or `*` as a statement introductory to enable or disable **statements**.

```
%if %sysget(USERNAME)=Richard %then %do;
  %let flag=*;
%end;
%else %do;
  %let flag=;
%end;

&flag. PROC PRINT ...;
&flag. ...;
&flag. ...;
&flag. run;
```

Comment: why use a macro comment, cann't  `/*...*/` do the same thing?

Comment: In SAS block commenting does not nest, so  `/* ...1... /* ...2... */ ...3... */` will not comment out `...3...`

Comment: I have to say that again, you are so knowledgeable. If you are a teacher, I would be your student.